# NET Core MVC - External API slow in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, api, .net-core

I am using an external API where response times from postman or my local machine are around ~500ms.

In production the same calls take around 10s. I could have understood if the overall page was slow in production but database calls and overall performance feels great. I am using RestRequest to perform the external calls.

This is my first dotnet core MVC project so I am a bit lost here. What could be the issues? Something with the hosting service?

EDIT: issue was the API. I guess they somehow recognized from where the call was coming from. Purchasing a key resolved the issue.

Comment: This seems like more of a firewall issue. Can you tell us where it's hosted. is the request https?

Comment: What is your hosting environment? is it equivalent in specification to dev? How about calls to a database (if you have one)? You could put some logging in your code to log out time stamps, this will prove or disprove if its time your your API spent processing the request, or time lost elsewhere (network IO etc).

Comment: It´s hosted at smarterasp.net using https. Dev is just my local PC so it differs quite heavily compared to production. Thanks I will try to include some logging. Edit. regarding database, i have tried using the production db from my dev machine and it works fine here as well. No performance issues there.